# What is this error `hook_civicrm_entityTypes` with cv?

Tags: cv

Trying to use `cv` we face this error

```
[RuntimeException] CiviCRM has not bootstrapped sufficiently to fire event "hook_civicrm_entityTypes".
```

Comment: Are you running cv from a directory inside the civicrm tree?

Comment: I have to check, where should it be run?

Comment: we did this at the root of the WP instance

Comment: Ok, then that's probably not the cause.